# Image upload error with Paperclip- Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, file-upload, paperclip

I am unable to upload the image as I am getting error in **upload** method of
user controller at line number 3 i.e. for **@user.update_attributes(params[:user])**.

**My upload method code** -

```
  def upload  
     @user = User.find_by_id(current_user.id)
   if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])  
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully uploaded Image."  
    if params[:user][:avatar].blank?  

      redirect_to @user  
    else  

      render :action => 'crop'  
    end  
  else  
    render :action => 'new'  
  end  
end
```

**My form** -

```
   <%= form_for(:user, :url => {:action => 'upload'}, 
  :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>

   <div class="inputs">

   <p>
     <%= f.label :avatar %>
     <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
   </p>
 </div>
   <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

**My user model -**

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:recoverable, 
      :rememberable,  :trackable, :validatable

      attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :avatar

      has_attached_file :avatar, 
      :styles  => { :small => "100x100#", :large  => "500x500>" }  

    end
```

**My output at command prompt -**

```
    identify: unable to open image `file':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2498.
    identify: no decode delegate for this image format `file' @ error/constitute.c     /ReadImage/532.

 Started POST "/users/upload" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-06 13:28:17 +0530
 Processing by UsersController#upload as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",  "authenticity_token"=>"mUPao835NCC8qXO553RJH50NWLhzQk03Z2G3Y0LwMYE=", 
"user"=>{"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xa20a418 @original_filename="freedomking.jpg",  @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-
 Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\";  filename=\"freedomking.jpg            
 \"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20121206-3368-127uzt5>>}, "commit"=>"Upload"}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
(1.1ms)  begin transaction
[paperclip] An error was received while processing:     
#<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /tmp/stream20121206-7054-b
teogf.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
[paperclip] An error was received while processing:    
#<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /tmp/stream20121206-7054-b
teogf.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
  (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

Comment: Can you post the user model, the part with has_attached_file :avatar. The problem come from paperclip.

Comment: Hey, I added the user model in the question if the paperclip seems to be the problem. Kindly check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution of my problem.

Steps:

1) Change `gem "paperclip"` to `gem "paperclip", "~> 3.3.1"` in a **gemfile**. This will  install the latest paperclip gem for your bundle. The previous one didn't.

2) Change in User Model's `has_attached_file`-

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
:path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment /:id/:style /:filename",
:url =>  "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename", 
:styles  => { :small => "100x100#", :large => "500x500>" }
```

This may help somebody who is experiencing such problem.

Cheers!

Comment: Valuable suggestion to notice. I thought that gemfile will always install the latest gem if we just give `gem gemname`.

Answer (score 0):

What format are you trying to upload? Is not a problem of Paperclip, but rather a problem with ImageMagick.

Paperclip uses ImageMagick for processing the images, by using the command identity. In order to be able to work with .jpg, .png, .gif, etc. you have to install ImageMagick with support for those formats and others as well.

The problem you have right now, is that it appears that you have ImageMagick installed, but without support for some image formats.

---

Ok, second try: Add the gem cocaine, rails usually works better when is high :P

```
gem "cocaine"
```

Comment: I have checked the ImageMagick support for image formats by issuing the following command at cmd: convert -list format. The formats .jpg, .png, .gif,etc found for ImageMagick with read write support. So consider as this is not a problem of format.

Comment: You also have made the right setup by telling paperclip where to findy the identify command, right, with:
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/" (could be any other path where you have the identify command)

Comment: My "/usr/local/bin/" was empty. So I explicitly checked in folders that where my ImageMagick is and found it under "usr/include". Then I gave path at initializer file as - Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/include/ImageMagick"

Comment: ok, just make sure that you can execute from the command line the command /usr/include/ImageMagick/identity
and also check my edit, and get some cocaine, I mean, add the gem cocaine to your Gemfile and don't forget to install it with bundle ;)

Comment: How to execute "/usr/include/ImageMagick/identity"?    On Cmd-      `$ /usr/include/ImageMagick/identity`
`bash: /usr/include/ImageMagick/identity: No such file or directory`

Comment: Also I got identify here- `$ whereis identify`
`identify: /usr/bin/identify /usr/share/man/man1/identify.1.gz`

Comment: I updated my question's heading "My output at command prompt" after noticing that jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.

Comment: Ok, so actually setup your app on config/initializer/paperclip.rb by doing Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/". Paperclip should find the command without problem on /usr/bin, but just in case. So if you have a .jpg file on the server, and you run: /usr/bin/identify my_file.jpg it doesn't work? If it doesn't work, then its probably my original answer, you need ImageMagick with support for jpg. What distribution do you have? or are you using mac?

Comment: Paperclip found command by - `/usr/bin$ /usr/bin/identify /home/user/Workspaces/eclipse/ocr_ws/ocr_tesseract/freedomking.jpg`
`/home/saurabh/Workspaces/eclipse/ocr_ws/ocr_tesseract/freedomking.jpg JPEG 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 45KB 0.000u0:00.000`

Comment: I am using Ubuntu, ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i686-linux], Rails 3.2.8.